# Python websockets not working with JavaScript audio streaming

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

So I am trying to send my user's audio to a server and save it in a file with the following code (Frontend is JavaScript, and the server is Python), it doesn't seem to work with no errors in the JavaScript, and Python console and an empty output.wav file.

```js
<script>
  const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
  const startRecordingButton = document.getElementById("start-recording");
  let mediaRecorder;

  startRecordingButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
    });

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    mediaRecorder.start();

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
      socket.send(event.data);
    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
      console.error("MediaRecorder error:", event);
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<button id="start-recording">Start Recording</button>
```

```
import asyncio
import wave
import websockets

with wave.open("output.wav", "wb") as wav_file:
    wav_file.setsampwidth(2)
    wav_file.setnchannels(1)
    wav_file.setframerate(16000)

    async def handle(websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
            data = message.data
            wav_file.writeframes(data)
    start_server = websockets.serve(handle, "localhost", 8080)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I've got the LTS Python, Pip, and the latest versions of the WebSocket package. I am trying to test this in the latest Google Chrome browser. What is wrong with this code?